# How to convert DNF expression to again normal Boolean expression

Tags: python

I have DNF formula like `"(a0 & a4) | (a1 & a4) | (a2 & a5) | (a4 & a5) | (a0 & a2 & a3) | (a1 & a2 & a3)"` I want it to convert again to a simplified form like it was before convert into DNF -> `"a2 & a1 & a3 | a2 & a5 | a2 & a0 & a3 | a4 & a1 | a4 & a5 | a4 & a0"`

I tried some functions of sympy.

Comment: code format and grammar fixes

Comment: Get rid of the parentheses?

Comment: DNF = a & b | a & c | a & d | b & e | c & e & f | d & e & f

Actual = a & ( b | c | d ) | e & b | e & f & ( c | d )

I want from DNF again back the actual formula